# Can a controller be in a seperate file when using ng-view?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

Currently I am learning AngularJS. I have made a 'hello world' app that displays through the ng-view directive. So far so good!

My files are ordered in this fashion:

```
- WebContent *(root)*
> - controllers *(folder)*
>> - controllers.js
> - views *(folder)*
>> - view1.html
>> - view2.html
> - index.html
```

The route config looks like this:

```
function routeConfig($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.when('/', 
{
templateUrl: "views/view1.html",
controller: "View1Ctrl"
}
).when("/view/:id", 
{
templateUrl: "views/view2.html",
controller: "View2Ctrl"
}
).otherwise(
{
redirectTo: "/"
});
};

app.controller("View1Ctrl", function($scope) {
$scope.message = "Hello World1";
}
[... etc. ...]
```

As I've mentioned before: this works perfectly fine. However, things might get more complex. The controllers could contains more functions etc. Is it possible to put these controllers in external files? So it would look something like this:

```
- WebContent *(root)*
> - controllers *(folder)*
>> - controllers.js
>> - view1-controller.js
>> - view2-controller.js
> - views *(folder)*
>> - view1.html
>> - view2.html
> - index.html
```

I already tried to simply import these files into the index:

```
<script src="controllers/view1-controller.js"></script>
```

But this did not seem to work. (It left me with a blanc page.) Hoping someone can help me out!

Comment: It is hard to predict based on only the directory location.
Can you please make a plunkr for the same?

Comment: I am not familiar with plunkr, but I think this is kind of what you asked:
https://plnkr.co/edit/PsLwqDwgH4WghyVmQVF9?p=catalogue

Comment: @RobertvanderSpek, I now see where your mistake lies. In `controllers/view1-controller.js` you create a new module, rather than retrieve it. Instead of `angular.module("App", ["ngRoute"]).controller(...`, you should write `angular.module("App").controller(...`.

Comment: Please add this comment as an answer, as it did answer my question! (Sometimes your staring so hard at the problem that the solution seems invisible, thanks for opening my eyes.)

Comment: It was already added as important note in mine ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dag Robert,

That certainly possible, even more I would recommend it! I'd like to refer you to this [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/iSUytnjSCW117n11TDQG?p=preview)

Basically you can just do something like this:

```
(function() {
  angular
    .module('plunker')
    .directive('helloWorld', function() {
      return {
        scope: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: 'HelloWorldController',
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        templateUrl: 'app/directives/hello-world/template.html'
      };
    })
})();
```

Important notes:

- To create a new module, you write: `angular.module('name',
  dependencies);`. Where the dependencies are an array.
- To retrieve the same module you don't write the dependencies:
  `angular.module('name')`. This will simply *get* the module

Comment: Although this works, it does not use the ng-view directive. Isn't it possible with ng-view (as this is as far as my knowledge of Angular goes at this moment).

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I'm not certain right now as I've quickly switched from the built-in views to [ui-views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), where this works in the exact way as I described here. Since you are just beginning, check out this: [angular-styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md). It gives great hints on how to format and group code.

Answer (score 1):

- WebContent (root)

  - controllers (folder)

  > Home.js
  >
  > Employee.js

  - views *(folder)

  > view1.html
  >
  > view2.html

  - index.html

this is index.js

`var myApp = angular.module('myApp');`
here is the seprate Home Controller (Home.js)

`myApp.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope) { }`

```
myApp.config(["$routeProvider",function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when("/Employees", {
    templateUrl: "templates/Employees/Employee.cshtml",
    controller: "EmployeeController"
})
.when("/Home", {
    templateUrl: "templates/Home/Home.cshtml"
})

.when("/EmployeeProgress", {
templateUrl: "templates/EmployeeStats/EmployeeStats.cshtml"
 })
.otherwise({
    templateUrl: "templates/Home/Home.cshtml"

});

}]);
```

here is the seprate  employee.js

`myApp.controller('EmployeeController',function ($scope) { }`

here is the seprate Home.js

`myApp.controller('HomeController',function ($scope) { }`